# Mirroring Eclipse Platform Aggregator Repository with Sub Modules

Tags: git

I am trying to mirror eclipse platform aggregator module (https://git.eclipse.org/r/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git) to a gitlab repository.

The purpose is to have the compete source (including submodules) hosted in a local repo, and build eclipse platform without accessing source code from external network.

Here are the steps followed

### Attempt 1

```
git clone --mirror https://git.eclipse.org/r/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git #with and without --recurse-submodules
git remote set-url --push origin ${local_repo_url}
git push --mirror # with and without --recurse-submodules=check
```

In first attempt , the contents got pushed to local repo. 
But while cloning the repository from local repo returned the following error

```
 a) Cloned Metadata       -> Successful
 b) Registered SubModules -> Succesful
 c) Clone Sub Modules     -> Failed

Cloning into 'path/eclipse-platform/eclipse.jdt'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'local_repo_url/jdt/eclipse.jdt.git/' not found
fatal: clone of local_repo/jdt/eclipse.jdt' into submodule 
path 'path/eclipse-platform/eclipse.jdt' failed
Failed to clone 'eclipse.jdt'. Retry scheduled
```

### Attempt 2

```
git clone https://git.eclipse.org/r/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.gi t --recurse-submodules #without mirror
git checkout master
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update
git remote set-url --push origin ${local_repo_url}
git push --mirror --recurse-submodules=check
```

But cloning from local repo , failed with same error (as in Attempt 1).
Any help to mirror this Repo along with submodules, to Gitab Repo , would be greatly appreciated

Thanks and Regards
Bipin.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you clone a submodule, the URL used in the `.gitmodules` file is used. Since that file is still the same as in the repository you're mirroring, Git will attempt to fetch that data from the original remote.

You'll need to mirror each repository individually on your local network. The data stored in a repository doesn't contain any data from its submodules, only the references in the `.gitmodules` directory.

As for solving the cloning problem, the easiest way to do that is to use a URL rewrite. So if you wanted to use `https://mirror.example.org/foo/` as your root instead of `https://git.eclipse.org/r/platform/`, you'd run the following command:

```
git config --global "url.https://mirror.example.org/foo/.insteadOf" https://git.eclipse.org/r/platform/
```

Note that you cannot make this configuration setting local to the repository, because when you clone a submodule, the settings of the parent repository are mostly ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, 1. How can I mirror all the submodules of eclipse repository to the internal repository in local network ? Attempt 2 in the problem description was done for achieving this.

Comment: You need to manually clone each repository you want to use, recursively, into an identical folder structure if you want to use it as a mirror (or script that process). So you'll need a repository for `platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git` and one for `jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git` and so on.